Kendo UI for Angular - filterable DropDownList - Search icon misaligned
I have the following code:
<kendo-dropdownlist formControlName="documentType" [data]="filteredDocumentTypes" [filterable]="true" [valuePrimitive]="true" textField="name" valueField="code" (filterChange)="filterDocumentTypes($event)" [class.is-invalid]="uploadDocumentType.invalid && isUploadInvalid"> </kendo-dropdownlist>
The built-in Search icon is misaligned (see screenshot below). It was ok before.

The screenshot also shows the automatic kendo-popup tag in the Browser Developer tools, seen when a user clicks in Choose Document Type dropdown. As this popup is very dynamic, I can't inspect further the Search icon in Developer Tools to see the automatic Kendo HTML tags and CSS classes so that I can potentially override a CSS class related to the icon.
How can I align the Search icon properly (to be at the beginning of the input field and vertically seen fully)?

Yes, you can view it. Search after the term 'emulate focused page'. In chrome, after pressing F12, press ctrl+shift+p, and type emulate focused page. And then enable it. After that the popup should be remain open.
